# Perl with reference to subroutine

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I'm trying to pass 2 arrays and a reference to a subroutine. It works well for the arrays but doesn't for the reference "$plistref". When I try to use it in the subroutine the same way I use it before, it doesn't work.

```
...
    my $locPlist = "conf.plist";
    my $configdict = NSDictionary->dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_($locPlist);
    my $plistref   = Foundation::perlRefFromObjectRef($configdict);

    my @contentMatchs;
    foreach ( @{ $plistref->{content_match} } ) {
        push @contentMatchs, $_->{match};
    }

    ....

    # Process the files
    _moveFile(\@files, \@contentMatchs, \$plistref);
}

sub _moveFile {
    my ($files_ref, $contentMatchs_ref, $plistref_ref) = @_;

    my @files           = @{ $files_ref };
    my @contentMatchs   = @{ $contentMatchs_ref };
    my $plistref        = $plistref_ref;

    my @spools = @{ $plistref->{SPOOLS} };
....
}
```

It tells me for the last line that "Not a HASH reference.."
I can't figure out how to pass this ref through the subroutine.

EDIT: I tried a workaround using "shift" and it worked! It doesn't look like the best option tho

```
    _moveFile($plistref, \@files, \@contentMatchs);
}

sub _moveFile {
    my $plistref        = shift;

    my ($files_ref, $contentMatchs_ref) = @_;
    my @files           = @{ $files_ref };
    my @contentMatchs   = @{ $contentMatchs_ref };
```

Thanks for your help!

-Tim.

Comment: I've tried that already, $plistref returns "1" in the subroutine :/

Comment: $plistref is a HASH tho

Comment: I rolled back the edit which removed all of the detail from this question. Please don't do that as it makes it almost impossible to make sense of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your "workaround" changed a few things. Originally, you had this:

```
_moveFile(\@files, \@contentMatchs, \$plistref);
```

And, in the subroutine, this:

```
sub _moveFile {
  my ($files_ref, $contentMatchs_ref, $plistref_ref) = @_;
```

After your workaround, you show us this:

```
_moveFile($plistref, \@files, \@contentMatchs);
```

And, in the subroutine, this:

```
sub _moveFile {
  my $plistref        = shift;
  my ($files_ref, $contentMatchs_ref) = @_;
```

You say that you "tried a workaround using `shift` and it worked!" But it's not the switch to using `shift` that fixed the problem. It was the change from passing `\$plistref` to passing `$plistref`.

You've obviously picked up that it's a good idea to pass arrays and hashes into subroutines using references. And that's great. But what you don't seem to have noticed is that `$plistref` is already a reference, so you don't need to take a reference to it again. By passing `\$plistref` in your original code, you were passing *a reference to a scalar containing a reference to a hash*. So Perl was quite correct to tell you that it was "not a HASH reference".

So, you can go back to most of your original code, just fixing the actual problem.

```
_moveFile(\@files, \@contentMatchs, $plistref);
```

And, in the subroutine, this:

```
sub _moveFile {
  my ($files_ref, $contentMatchs_ref, $plistref_ref) = @_;
```

And everything will work as you want. The `shift` was a complete red herring.

Answer (score 2):

`_moveFile(\@files, \@contentMatchs, \$plistref);` here, you are passing a reference to a HASHREF as the third argument.  I.e., a reference to a reference to a HASH.  You don't need the to pass the HASHREF as a reference as it already is one.  I.e., call your subroutine like this: `_moveFile(\@files, \@contentMatchs, $plistref);`

If for some reason, you wanted to pass a reference to a HASHREF, you could dereference the value like this: `${$plistref}->{SPOOLS}`.

`_moveFile($plistref, \@files, \@contentMatchs);` here, in your edit, you're passing a HASHREF as the first argument.  This is why using `my $plistref = shift` works - the variable has the expected level of referencing.

Answer (score 0):

`\$plistref` is a reference to a scalar.  To dereference it in the function, you need to say

```
my $plistref        = ${ $plistref_ref };
```